# Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized when trying to access secure proxy wso2 esb

Tags: java, ssl, wso2-esb

I'm new trying to secure a web service (which is not secure) using a proxy service via wso2 esb.

```
OrderServiceStub stub = new OrderServiceStub("https://localhost:8243/services/OPSecureService");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "resources/wso2carbon.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");

HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator authenticator = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
authenticator.setUsername(username);
authenticator.setPassword(password);

Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, authenticator);
System.out.println(stub.getCatlog(new GetCatlog()));
```

But I'm getting

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
```

And on the ESB log it says

```
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: SOAP Envelope can not have children other than SOAP Header and Body
```

I'm able to access the service through the tryit service in the esb management console using username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by setting the following property to true.

```
options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.ENABLE_REST, Constants.VALUE_TRUE);
```

But can someone tell me why I couldn't run the client without enabling REST communication